# Update/Refresh a hidden parameter in SSRS after action operation in line chart

Tags: ssrs-2008, action, drilldown

I am new to SSRS report. I have a SSRS report in which have a main report with Line chart and a sub report to show the detail.
In line chart on click of the data point(series property) have to update the sub report detail on the basis of the data point value. For getting the value of the selected line chart have used a hidden parameter and which is then passed to the sub report to get the respective data..

I have some parameters also so on selection of one of the parameter's i have to reset the hidden parameter value but the value is not reset and showing the last value set using the line chart action property.

Is there any way I can reset the hidden parameter after updating the drill down report. I am using web service to show the data in the report.

Thanks in advance

Supriya Khamesra

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you whishing to reset a parameter that you getting from a main report into a subreport, you can do as following:
From the sub-report you can send the parameter back to the main report and put in the action screen/parameters - hard coded value which will "reset" your parameter. that way the parameter in the main report always be reset according to the hard-coded value you putted in the subreport.

Comment: I have to show the sub report below the main report and not in a separate report. So,is it possible to pass the parameter to main report from sub report.

Comment: so in this case, in the main report you should use the "action" screen and send the parameter to the sub report with a value which is based according to the selected chart. when you wish to 'reset' the parameter with other parameters you just pass the same parameter to the subreport - but now with different "fixed" value that you define.

Comment: I am using the action only to pass the parameter and setting the hidden parameter value but my issue is if I select any parameter from the parameter panel of main report i want to reset the hidden parameter or if possible when sub report get displayed the hidden parameter can be updated.